# NSTimer code is executing forever

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here is my code. I expected the timer to stop in 5 second after it starts but it doesn't. What is wrong here ?

```
-(void)loadView
{
NSTimeInterval startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];



NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
if([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - startTime >= 5) {
    [timer invalidate];
}

}

-(void)targetMethod:(NSTimer *)timer {


    NSLog(@"bla");
}
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how `NSTimer` works because the code in `targetMethod:` doesn't make any sense. What are trying to do?

Comment: I forgot to add the targetMethod. Please see the updated version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSDate's timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate is, by default, returning January 1st, 2001. Subtracting the same values will always be 0.

Apple's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Here's an idea:
In your .h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;

- (void)targetMethod:(NSTimer *)timer;
- (void)cancelTimer;

@end
```

In your .m

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize timer;

-(void)loadView
{
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(cancelTimer) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}

-(void)cancelTimer {
    [self.timer invalidate];
}

-(void)targetMethod:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSLog(@"bla");
}
```

Comment: Well, what to do so to stop the timer after 5 second since it's start ?

Comment: I put the code in there to demonstrate. startTime will need to be a property of your class, as NSTimeInterval.

Comment: I tried your code, but it still output bla string forever. The timer not stop.

Comment: Okay, I'll change to a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is short and simple:

```
NSDate *endtime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
         target:self
         selector:@selector(timerTick:)
         userInfo:endtime
         repeats:YES];


-(void)timerTick:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    NSLog(@"timer tick");
    if ( [timer.userInfo timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0 )
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        NSLog(@"invalidating timer");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your time difference is always 0 so you never invalidate it!

Try setting startTime before you set the timer.

Comment: You need startTime in a property variable. And your timer code should me placed in your method named targetMethod:.

Answer (score 0):

You get the 'startTime' value and the value you compare it to are identical. Your calculation will always give 0. You must store the 'startTime' in your loadView method and then use it in the calculation.